# Exim4 DKIM Configuration Does not Work on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, exim, dkim, debian-jessie

I am using exim4 4.84.2-2+deb8u1 on Debian Jessie. Below I have replaced some domain names with example.com.

I have a split configuration with `dc_use_split_config='true'` in the `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` file.

In the file `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_macros` I have:

```
DKIM_CANON = relaxed
DKIM_SELECTOR = 20161213
DKIM_DOMAIN = example.com
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem
```

After running `update-exim4.conf` with root I have config above at the top of the `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated` file after a comment.

```
#########
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# This file was generated dynamically from
# split config files in the /etc/exim4/conf.d/ directory.
# The config files are supplemented with package installation/configuration
# settings managed by debconf. This data is stored in
# /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf
# Any changes you make here will be lost.
# See /usr/share/doc/exim4-base/README.Debian.gz and update-exim4.conf(8)
# for instructions of customization.
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
# WARNING WARNING WARNING
#########
DKIM_CANON = relaxed
DKIM_SELECTOR = 20161213
DKIM_DOMAIN = example.com
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem
```

There is more to the file of-course.

I restart exim with `service exim4 restart`. I notice the correct config parameters are not being shown when I run this command:

```
# exim -bP | grep example.com
primary_hostname = example.com
qualify_domain = example.com
qualify_recipient = example.com
```

When I send mail, no DKIM signature is added.

The private key permissions and owner are:

```
# ls -la /etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem
-rw------- 1 root Debian-exim 887 Dec 13 10:23 /etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem
```

The logs when sending an email are:

```
2016-12-15 12:54:01 exim 4.84_2 daemon started: pid=6159, -q30m, listening for SMTP on [127.0.0.1]:25 [::1]:25
2016-12-15 12:54:01 Start queue run: pid=6160
2016-12-15 12:54:01 1cHHnz-0006uo-SS Message is frozen
2016-12-15 12:54:01 1cH6QF-00069Q-Dt Message is frozen
2016-12-15 12:54:01 1cGvKR-0005Pd-HK Message is frozen
2016-12-15 12:54:01 1cGYkT-0003lm-Ti == 11566195@www3.l.google.com <11566195@support.google.com> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host
2016-12-15 12:54:01 1cHTcJ-0007j9-Ob Message is frozen
2016-12-15 12:54:01 End queue run: pid=6160
2016-12-15 12:54:07 1cHbAM-0001bW-Sl <= donotreply@example.com H=localhost (server01.example.com) [::1] P=esmtp S=8004
2016-12-15 12:54:09 1cHbAM-0001bW-Sl => someemail@example.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mx.example.com [66.96.140.95] X=TLS1.0:RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1:128 DN="C=US,O=Sample\, Inc.,OU=IT Team,CN=Server" C="250 LJwY1u03o4xYfnm01 mail accepted for delivery"
2016-12-15 12:54:09 1cHbAM-0001bW-Sl Completed
```

How do I get DKIM to work and for exim to recognise my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include the following configuration option:

```
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = /etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem
```

And to make the user owner of the key `Debian-exim`.